# forever node.js - watch directory for file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I want my node application `index.js` to be restarted if there is any file change detected in its directory or below. Additionally, I want the process to be in the foreground, outputting logs to the terminal. What is the command?

My tries:

`forever stopall`

`forever -w /home/patrick/workspace/frontend-api/index.js`

Result:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
error: Could not read .foreverignore file.
error: ENOENT, open '/.foreverignore'
error: restarting script because unlinkDir changed

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: watch EACCES
    at errnoException (fs.js:1024:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1056:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1081:11)
```

Comment: Do you have well configured `.foreverignore` file ?

Comment: I do not have such a file and it is not mentioned on the offical documentation before running...

Comment: Also there are similar issues https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/660 , https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/235, try to add .foreverignore file and may you give a feedback about it I can add as an answer.

Comment: added the file: `error: Could not read .foreverignore file.
error: ENOENT, open '/.foreverignore'
error: restarting script because unlinkDir changed
`

Comment: @ShlomoGoldstein did you ever find a fix for this? I've hit the *exact* same error and this is the _only_ hit on google that matches the scenario perfectly. No solution?

Comment: Sorry I did not find a solution and switched to nodemon.

Comment: I'm amazed that there doesn't seem to be a straight up answer to this question. I've found a few threads across here and github that point to the problem, but not a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like u need nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

however in my windows server i used `https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode` good for scalability on multi core servers

Comment: oh sry my bad, after this replace node with nodemon ,like if u used `node app.js` earlier , now use `nodemon app.js` . 

After this whenever u make any change in any file , it vl restart server for u , good for development env. 
plz accept or upvote if it helps

Comment: nodemon is good for dev environment , for production go with forever or iisnode

Answer (score 9):

From what I understand (the documentation on this is non-existent from what I can see). the `-w` or `--watch` function makes forever check for a `.foreverignore` file, and if this is missing the program essentially fails and gets stuck in a loop never starting the module.

in your app directory create a file called `.foreverignore` and list everything that you do not want forever to watch. This basically tells forever to ignore changes to these files and not to restart if anything happens to them, which is great for log files or things that don't actually require your module to restart to get the benefits from.

Here's an example taken from my implementation:

File:

```
/apps/myapp/.foreverignore
```

Contents

```
node_modules/*
logs/*
conf/*
htdocs/*
*.log
*.gif
*.jpg
*.html
```

Once created make sure you restart forever for the file to be picked up.

Comment: this is the correct answer and should have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @stuffyjoelab `forever -w` checks for a `.foreverignore` file, and will get stuck if it's not there.

Here's my simple approach to adding `forever` to a node server project.

1. create `.foreverignore`

   ```
   # we only care about changes to javascript files
   # in the src folder
   !src/*.js
   ```
2. `npm i -D forever` to add `forever` as a dev-dependency
3. add this to the scripts in your package.json file

   ```
   "dev": "forever -w --minUptime=1000 --spinSleepTime=1000 index.js",
   ```
4. `npm run dev` to start it up with forever.
5. Change a file and voila — your server reboots